# How i use google drive link for web hosting on a site like Host Gator?

Tags: html, css, hosting

I have my web page(css/html) files stored in the google drive. When I click on the google drive link, I can see the web page opening on my local browser.
I tried replacing the name server with this link on the domain that I had bought from HostGator, it is not accepting this link as name server. How can I fix this ?

EDIT:

TO add more info, I tried adding the "google drive link" to both "Name Servers" and "private name servers" .

Details:
Hostname:Static, IP Address: "Google Drive Link"

I saw this error:

> An error occurred. Please verify the validity of your nameservers and
>   try again.

Answer (score -1):

You need to buy a server from a hosts and they will provide you with the server ip and then you can link it to your Domain